# Updating a multi value cookie in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I update a multi-value cookie in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
public ActionResult ModifyCookie()
{
    // Read the cookie from the request
    var cookie = Request.Cookies["cookieName"];

    // Verify that the cookie was present
    if (cookie != null)
    {
        // modify a value given the key
        cookie.Values["key"] = "modified value";

        // write the modified cookie back to the response
        Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Response.AppendCookie(...) was, what I was missing. Thanks.

Comment: Actually should updating an existing cookie be:

`Response.SetCookie(cookie)`

Response.AppendCookie just adds the cookie to the collection.